# Fix `pyqtSlot` decorator name to `pyQtSlot`

Tags: pyqt5

I really think having `pyqtSlot` as a decorator name is inconsistent. We should really fix this to `pyQtSlot`.

Comment: I'm not in love with the current naming scheme, but `pyQtSlot` just looks confusing and wrong. It is far too suggestive of Qt module names like `QtCore`, `QtGui`, etc. I think it would have been much better to use a proper namespace, so that we could have had `pyqt.slot`, `pyqt.signal`, and so forth. But that ship has long since sailed, so it's pointless debating it now.

Comment: Well, the namespace is pretty f*cked up, yes. Since the naming scheme of PyQt is camelcase, I therefore don’t understand why they named pyqtSlot the way the did. This is what is confusing and wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was because `pyQtSlot` suggests a parsing of `py` + `QtSlot`. If the slot and signal objects were *classes*, rather than functions, they could have been named `PyQtSlot` and `PyQtSignal` - or, even better, just `Slot` and `Signal`, as they are in PySide.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution is

`from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot as pyQtSlot`